# Only specific apps for action.send

Tags: android, android-intent, send

i want to send link from my app. I use the following code:

```
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share"));
```

This brings up a dialog with some Apps. But now I would like to filter this list, i.e. I would like to remove the Blutooth app.

How can i remove apps from this dialog?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "remove apps from this dialog" directly.

You are welcome to use `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()` and present your own custom dialog of stuff. However, you will not be able to reliably identify "the Bluetooth app", since extent there is anything that might qualify on a given device, it may have different names based upon device manufacturer.